# Conditional formatting using a string indicator, between different sheets in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Hi hopefully a simple one - but am struggling with it.

I have 2 cell ranges: A1:A10 in SheetA and B1:B10 in SheetB

On sheetB, B1:B10 has Xs (i.e. “X”) in some cells, the others have numbers in them.

I would like to colour the cells on SheetA in the A1:A10 range black (for example) if the corresponding SheetB cell has an X in it.

Am applying the following custom formula in conditional formatting on sheetA to cells A1:A10:

=if(indirect("SheetB!B1:B10")="X",1,0)=1

But cannot get it to work either like or on several variations - have tried match variants also for example. Similar questions don't seem to address this admittedly basic ask.

Thanks for any and all advice/help.

Comment: share you example if you can

Answer (score 1):

try custom formula set to range A1:A10 on your SheetA:

```
=INDIRECT("SheetB!B1:B10")="X"
```